# Why is this use of Promise.finally leading to uncaught exception?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am implementing a function called `timeout` to convert a promise into a promise that will reject if not settled within a minimum amount of time.

With the following implementation, I get an `uncaught (in promise)` message in Chrome devtools when the promise passed to `timeout` rejects before the allotted time.

```
function timeout(promise, duration, message) {
    const timeoutPromise = new Promise((_, reject) => {
        const handle = setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new TimeoutError(message ?? "Operation timed out."))
        }, duration)
        promise.finally(() => clearTimeout(handle)) //problem line
    })
    return Promise.race([promise, timeoutPromise])
}
```

If I change it to the following however, I seem to have no issues.

```
function timeout(promise, duration, message) {
    const timeoutPromise = new Promise((_, reject) => {
        const handle = setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new TimeoutError(message ?? "Operation timed out."))
        }, duration)
        const clear = () => clearTimeout(handle)
        promise.then(clear).catch(clear)
    })
    return Promise.race([promise, timeoutPromise])
}
```

I'm trying to understand how calling `then` & `catch` in the second scenario is different to calling `finally` in the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `finally` handlers are different from `then` and `catch` handlers. If the promise is rejected, a `finally` handler can't change rejection to resolution. Like the `finally` block of a `try`/`catch`/`finally` structure, it's meant to be largely transparent.

Here's how I describe it in my new book (Chapter 8):

> In the normal case, a `finally` handler has no effect on the fulfillment or rejection passing through
> it (like a `finally` block): any value it returns other than a thenable that is/gets rejected is
> ignored. But if it throws an error or returns a thenable that rejects, that error/rejection supersedes
> any fulfillment or rejection passing through it (just like throw in a `finally` block). So it can't change
> a fulfillment value — not even if it returns a different value — but it can change a rejection reason into a
> different rejection reason, it can change a fulfillment into a rejection, and it can delay a fulfillment (by
> returning a thenable that is ultimately fulfilled).
>
> Or to put it another way: it's like a `finally` block that can't contain a `return` statement. (It might
> have a `throw` or might call a function or do some operation that throws, but it can't return a new value.

Here's an example of not being able to convert rejection to fulfillment:

```js
Promise.reject(new Error("Failed"))
.finally(() => {
    console.log("finally handler returns null");
    return null;
});
```

```html
Look in the browser's real console to see the unhandled rejection error.
```

---

Another way to deal with it in your code is to do this in place of the problem line:

```
promise.catch(() => {}).finally(() => clearTimeout(handle))
```

or

```
promise.catch(() => {}).then(() => clearTimeout(handle))
```

That converts rejection to fulfillment (only on this branch) prior to the `finally` (or `then`) handler.